# Overlapping conditions for CSS jQuery Coloring of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I think that I've jFiddled myself into a corner here.  I've got a customer project where I'm tracking system migration status from one domain to another.  My tool I've created has a web page utility that people can use to track a migration.  I'm currently a bit confused, trying to identify where I've made a mistake in my css.

My tool will export an HTML file which will have a few conditions:

- If the migration status equals Needs Attention, color the row red, overlapping any other conditions
- If the migration status equals Migrated, color the row green, overlapping any other conditions
- If the migration status equals ReadyForMigration, color the row yellow

So, for some reason, it seems like my jquery $(this) selector doesn't work on the first cell in a row, but will work on other cells in the row.

Any idea why only some of these cells are receiving their coloration?

[image]

Fiddler link : http://jsfiddle.net/6zjggL9j/4/

## jquery

```
$('tbody tr td:not(":first")').each(

function() {
var cell = $(this).text();



if (cell == 'Not Online') {
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('NotOnline')
}


else if (cell == 'Migrated') {
    $(this).addClass('good');
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('good')
}

else if (cell == 'ReadyForMigration') {
    $(this).addClass('Available');
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('Available')
}

else if (cell == 'Available') {
    $(this).addClass('Available');
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('Available')
}

});
```

## css

```
table {
    width: 20em;
}

th {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 0.5em 2em 0.1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

td {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0.5em 0 0.1em 0;
}

.vGood {
    background-color: #0f0;
}

.Online {
    background-color: #0f0;
}
.good {
    background-color: #0c0;
}

.avg {
    background-color: #060;
}

.poor {
    background-color: #c00;
}

.vPoor {
    background-color: #f00;
}

.Migrated{}

.Online{
background-color: #fd0;
    }

.NotOnline {
  background-color: #a44   
}

.Available{
  background-color: #dca
}
}
```

## html

```
<table id="my_table">
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<thead>
<tr><th>MigrationStatus</th><th>User</th><th>ComputerName</th><th>Location</th><th>Ipv4</th><th>Domain</th><th>Online</th></tr>
</thead>
<tr><td>ReadyForMigration</td><td>NA</td><td>5101TEST-LI</td><td>##</td><td>10.24.130.74</td><td>Source</td><td>Available</td></tr>
<tr><td>Needs Attention</td><td>NA</td><td>ABBON-L2</td><td>##</td><td>??</td><td>Access Denied</td><td>Not Online</td></tr>
<tr><td>Needs Attention</td><td>NA</td><td>ABBON-L7</td><td>##</td><td>??</td><td>Access Denied</td><td>Not Online</td></tr>
<tr><td>Needs Attention</td><td>NA</td><td>ACCTGTEMP-L</td><td>##</td><td>??</td><td>Access Denied</td><td>Not Online</td></tr>
<tr><td>Migrated</td><td>NA</td><td>ADAMSL-D</td><td>##</td><td>??</td><td>Corp</td><td>Not Online</td></tr>
<tr><td>Migrated</td><td>NA</td><td>AGRUSSA-LI</td><td>##</td><td>??</td><td>Corp</td><td>Online</td></tr>
<tr><td>ReadyForMigration</td><td>NA</td><td>HamsterMan</td><td>##</td><td>??</td><td>Source</td><td> Online</td></tr>
</table>
```

If this is anything like the last problem I had, I made a silly mistake and you'll see the cause in moments.  Thanks in advance

Comment: I think my problem is that I need to remove the 'NotOnline' class when I'm setting 'Migrated', but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: why do you say `td:not(:first)` if you want the first cell?

Comment: @DanDavis, I'm kind of new to jQuery.  Could you explain what my first selector is doing for me?  I started off with that from an example I found online.

Comment: it returns all the cells that are in rows, except for the first cell in each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea you're trying to target all the `td`s, but it is only necessary to target the `tr`

http://jsfiddle.net/6zjggL9j/5/

Changed the code

```
else if (cell == 'Migrated') {
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('good')
}
```

to remove the td class add. Did this for all cases.

**Edit** yes I overlooked the removing class thing. You should remove all other classes and then add the class you want it to be. That is going to be the best practice..